# Why does the piston not move?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

[image]

in this figure, the two blocks are pistons (plss ignore the straight line)

assuming there is  an ideal gas of pressure 1 atm  in the system(between the pistons)::

I don't understand why the pistons won't move
if the 1 atm acts from the left and 1 atm acts from the right shouldn't the total pressure be 2 atm ???